# HQL trying to count number of instances where variable falls outside interquartile range (IQR)

Tags: hadoop, hql

I'm trying to count the number of instances where a variable 'ASSESS_WEIGHT' falls outside  interquartile range (IQR). IQR max and min have already been calculated and are stored in metric_value where metric_description is 'MAX_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT' and 'MIN_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT'. metric_value is a decimal number.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts, ASSESS_WEIGHT 
    FROM ASSESSMENT_INSTANCE 
        WHERE 
            ASSESS_WEIGHT >= (SELECT metric_value 
                              FROM data_quality 
                              WHERE metric_description = 'MAX_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT')
        OR 
            ASSESS_WEIGHT <= (SELECT metric_value 
                              FROM data_quality 
                              WHERE metric_description = 'MIN_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT')
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm running this in HQL on Hortonworks Hive query editor.

Thank you!

Comment: also ASSESS_WEIGHT is a decimal number

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts, ASSESS_WEIGHT 
FROM ASSESSMENT_INSTANCE 
GROUP BY ASSESS_WEIGHT
HAVING 
ASSESS_WEIGHT >= (SELECT metric_value 
                  FROM data_quality 
                  WHERE metric_description = 'MAX_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT')
OR
ASSESS_WEIGHT <= (SELECT metric_value 
                  FROM data_quality 
                  WHERE metric_description = 'MIN_IQR_ASSESS_WEIGHT')`

Comment: I've also modified the first WHERE clause to a GROUP BY ASSESS_WEIGHT HVING ASSESS_WEIGHT >= etc. and still no luck